# Dynamic query search/filter on javascript object returning parent and children

Tags: javascript, nested

In my app I have a nested object (basic object, not using SQL) that consists of parents and children that is rendered as an outline like this:

```
-  item 1
    ⁃   Child 1
        ⁃   Grand 1 (date = May 21)
        ⁃   Grand 2
            ⁃   More children 1
            ⁃   More children 2
               ⁃    [could be infinitely deep]
    ⁃   Child 2
        ⁃   grandchild1
        ⁃   Grandchild 2
            ⁃   [could be infinitely deep]
```

Each object has properties like this:

```
{
    Name: “item 1”,
    Date: June 3 2017,
    Children: [ …children]
}
```

I have a search box where a user can enter in a term and which returns any matching object, plus its parents and children. For example, is someone searches “Grand 2” it will look like this:

```
-   item 1
    ⁃   Child 1
        ⁃   **Grand 2**
            ⁃   More children 1
            ⁃   More children 2
                ⁃   [could be infinitely deep]
```

Here is the code I use for filtering and it works well:

```
export const filterTree = (filter, list) => {
    return _.filter(list, (item) => {
        if (_.includes(_.toLower(item.name), _.toLower(filter))) {
          item.collapsed = false;
            return true;
        } else if (item.children) {
          item.collapsed = false;
            item.children = filterTree(filter, item.children);
            return !_.isEmpty(item.children);
        }
    });
};
```

What I am struggling with is combining searches like this “Grand 2 OR date = May 21 2017”. Which would return this.

```
•   item 1
    ⁃   Child 1
        ⁃   Grand 1 (date = May 21)
        ⁃   Grand 2
            ⁃   More children 1
            ⁃   More children 2
                ⁃   [could be infinitely deep]
```

Comment: I would advise parameterization the filter logic by accepting a function and calling it instead of testing for a string: `if (_.includes(_.toLower(item.name), _.toLower(filter)))` would become `if (filter(item))`

Comment: I removed the react & redux tags from this question, as the problem is valid in any javascript environment.